# Node.js and AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: node.js, express, aws-code-deploy

I've written a quick application using Express and Node.js. I can run it locally, and it works.

How do I get it to deploy and run the server on CodeDeploy? Do I need to add something to the appsec?

Answer (score 2):

Appsec file is the right place to set up your hooks for CodeDeploy deployment. During each lifecycle event, CodeDeploy Host Agent will execute the hooks you have in the Appsec file under each lifecycle event. In your case, you might want several scripts to stop the running server, change the configuration and restart the server. For more information about how Appsec file works, take a reference here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html